# Simulating Human Models for use with turtlebot tracking

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey,

How would I go about simulating a human model in gazebo such that I can track legs with the turtlebot follower package. I have the turtlebot simulated in gazebo using the turtlebot_simulator package.

I'm Currently using version 1.9.1 of gazebo.
I'm also running ros hydro if that helps.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4540/simulating-human-models-for-use-with-turtlebot-tracking/) by [Alkaros](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/505/alkaros/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

there once was an actor implementation for this kind of things (v1.0 which is really outdated).
The actor is not really simulated but can be used to play animations.

This was not maintained in the last releases and does not work at the moment.

I'm not sure if someone is really working one this feature right now.

you might want to read this post:

[animated-human-characters-in-gazebo](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3159/animated-human-characters-in-gazebo/)

if you really need the animation you can help re-implementing/debugging this feature

The only way to control an actor was to define everything before starting in a script. You can look at the old tutorial for information how it worked:

[wiki entry: animated characters](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/intermediate/animated_characters)

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1